# Enable/disable intent-filter in Android app programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, controls

I have one Activity in AndroidManifest.xml with 2 Intent-filters:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.test" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
</activity>
```

When I touch phone with NFC card based on the intent-filters my app is triggered.
Can I add other combination of activity/activity-alias/intent-filters and later control it in my app's settings with something like this to disable my app to react on NFC card touch?

```
   pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                compName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

I have checked other answers, but it stil doesn't work. Sometimes I get 2 app icons in the launcher.
Please help.